# how to store value from one procedure to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have created procedure called UTILITY_SERVICES_SP_DELETE_SCHPAY that procedure is used in sp_del_benmast procedure.
i neead to store called procedure value into P_SUC_FLAG,P_ERROR variable.
Is this possible to do.
or should i convert UTILITY_SERVICES_SP_DELETE_SCHPAY procedure into function

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM UTILITY_SERVICES_SP_DELETE_SCHPAY(P_ENTITY_CODE, P_CUST_CODE, IDY.SRV_REF_NUM, P_SUC_FLAG, P_ERROR) 
  INTO STRICT P_SUC_FLAG,P_ERROR;
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) you need `select ... INTO STRICT ... FROM ...`  But if `UTILITY_SERVICES_SP_DELETE_SCHPAY ` is a procedure, you can use it in a `select * from` anyway

Comment: can i store UTILITY_SERVICES_SP_DELETE_SCHPAY output into P_SUC_FLAG,P_ERROR variables